# partizip 2 lassen usage

Tags: modal-verb, past-participle, verbal-complex

I have a question regarding following quote:

> Was die Alarmglocken eines jeden Steuerexperten hätte aufschrillen lassen müssen,
>      ließ die Fachleute der Deutschen Bank offenbar kalt.

Why are there like 3 infinitives stacked together? And why is there *hätte* without partizip 2 following it? I could've understood if it were *aufschrillen lassen gemusst*. Can you refer to some grammatical article explaining this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence can be derived like this, by adding one verb at a time:

> Die Alarmglocken schrillen auf.
>   Das **läßt** die Alarmglocken **aufschrillen**. (lassen + Infinitiv; "kausativ")
>   Das **muß** die Alarmglocken aufschrillen **lassen**. (müssen + Infinitiv)
>   Das **hätte** die Alarmglocken aufschrillen lassen **müssen**. (haben + Ersatzinfinitiv)

In the perfect, modal verbs use the [Ersatzinfinitiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv) instead of the Partizip 2 (as long as  they are combined with another infinitive, such as *lassen* in this case).

Since your sentence  is verb-final and there are two or more non-finite verbs in the end, you also get an unexpected position for *hätte*: it occurs in front of the other verbs and not in last position. The position has been called [Oberfeld](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Grammatik#Reihenfolge_der_Verben).

> was die Alarmglocken **hätte** aufschrillen lassen müssen

Comment: danke, ersatzinfinitiv erklärt das